# Js замена одного тега на другой

Tags: javascript, html

Как с помощью js можно изменить тег br на div?

```
   class="test"><br><b>text</b>: 123<br>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="
```

на

```
    class="test"><div class="new class"><b>text</b>: 123</div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="
```

Comment: надо писать нормальный код, а не костыли

Answer (score 0):

Как выше ужа сказали, можно удалить и вставить новый элемент. Может не самое оптимальное решение, но конкретно для Вашей ситуации может подойти.

```js
let test = document.querySelector('.test'); //получаем родительский контейнер
let link = test.querySelector('a');//получаем ссылку
let b = test.querySelector('b');// получаем b

let div = document.createElement('div'); // Создаем новый div
//Вставляем в новый div b.textContent(текстовый контент тега b), и текстовый контент следующего за тегом b узла.
div.innerHTML = '<b>' + b.textContent + '</b>' + b.nextSibling.textContent;
div.className = 'new class'; //добавляем класс новому div
test.innerHTML = ''; // очищаем родительский контейнер
test.appendChild(div); // вставляем в очищенный контейнер новый div
test.appendChild(link); // следом вставляем ссылку
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <br><b>text</b>: 123<br>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">a</a>
</div>
```